# I want to fetch specific values from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

String 1:

```
{cm_documentation_.chk_phone_call_physician}=1 & 
{cm_documentation_.txt_phone_call_code}="99441"  &   
({cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}!="" & ({local.units_mins}<5 |
{local.units_mins}>10) | {cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}="")
```

String 2:

```
{@This}="93015" | {@This}="78454" | {@This}="78453" | {@This}="78452" |   
{@This}="78451" | {@This}="78480" | {@This}="78478" | {@This}="78465" |  
{@This}="78499" | {@This}="78492" | {@This}="78491" | {@This}="78459"
```

I want to fetch values after `=` symbol

```
Result: 
99441
93015
78454
78453
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
So on.....

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression? If not, look that up to get closer to the solution.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012 is information you've provided in the tags. Your question title has no meaning. Please [edit] to make it descriptive of the question you're asking or the problem you are experiencing. You've not given any information about either of those. Please visit [ask], and then [edit] to meet those requirements.

Comment: I have used Reg expressions, to fetch the values but, I want all those values in a single column.

Comment: string manipulation is not sql server's strong suit. This kind of thing is better handled in a programming language outside of sql server.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you are looking for String1

However, with a Parse/Split function

```
Declare @String2 varchar(max) = '{@This}="93015" | {@This}="78454" | {@This}="78453" | {@This}="78452" |  
{@This}="78451" | {@This}="78480" | {@This}="78478" | {@This}="78465" |  
{@This}="78499" | {@This}="78492" | {@This}="78491" | {@This}="78459" '

Select RetSeq
      ,RetVal=Replace(Substring(RetVal,PatIndex('%[0-9]%',RetVal),25),'"','') 
 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String2,'|')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       93015
2       78454
3       78453
4       78452
5       78451
6       78480
7       78478
8       78465
9       78499
10      78492
11      78491
12      78459
```

**The UDF if needed**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select @String as [*] For XML Path('')),@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this a few ways. To get what I believe the OP is looking for the solution you could make a slight tweak to John Cappelletti's solution so that it looks like this:

```
DECLARE 
@string1 varchar(1000) = 
'{cm_documentation_.chk_phone_call_physician}=1 & 
{cm_documentation_.txt_phone_call_code}="99441"  &   
({cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}!="" & ({local.units_mins}<5 |
{local.units_mins}>10) | {cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}="")',

@string2 varchar(1000) = 
'{@This}="93015" | {@This}="78454" | {@This}="78453" | {@This}="78452" |   
{@This}="78451" | {@This}="78480" | {@This}="78478" | {@This}="78465" |  
{@This}="78499" | {@This}="78492" | {@This}="78491" | {@This}="78459"';

Select RetVal
From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@string1 + @string2,'"')
where RetVal NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```

Note that the fastest string "splitter" I know of for SQL 2012+ can be found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/).

Another option would be to use PatternSplitCM which you can get [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/). And do this:

```
DECLARE 
@string1 varchar(1000) = 
'{cm_documentation_.chk_phone_call_physician}=1 & 
{cm_documentation_.txt_phone_call_code}="99441"  &   
({cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}!="" & ({local.units_mins}<5 |
{local.units_mins}>10) | {cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}="")',

@string2 varchar(1000) = 
'{@This}="93015" | {@This}="78454" | {@This}="78453" | {@This}="78452" |   
{@This}="78451" | {@This}="78480" | {@This}="78478" | {@This}="78465" |  
{@This}="78499" | {@This}="78492" | {@This}="78491" | {@This}="78459"';

SELECT item = REPLACE(item,'"','')
FROM dbo.PatternSplitCM(@string1 + @string2,'[0-9"]')
WHERE matched = 1
AND item LIKE '"[0-9]%"';
```

Now, if you you are always searching for this pattern ([0-9] = a number): ="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" the fastest way would be like this to use [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) like this:

```
DECLARE 
@string1 varchar(1000) = 
'{cm_documentation_.chk_phone_call_physician}=1 & 
{cm_documentation_.txt_phone_call_code}="99441"  &   
({cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}!="" & ({local.units_mins}<5 |
{local.units_mins}>10) | {cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}="")',

@string2 varchar(1000) = 
'{@This}="93015" | {@This}="78454" | {@This}="78453" | {@This}="78452" |   
{@This}="78451" | {@This}="78480" | {@This}="78478" | {@This}="78465" |  
{@This}="78499" | {@This}="78492" | {@This}="78491" | {@This}="78459"';

SELECT token = SUBSTRING(token,3,5)
FROM dbo.NGrams8K(@string1 + @string2,8)
WHERE token LIKE '="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"';
```

Alternatively, let's say you know the numbers you are parsing out were, say, 3 to 5 characters long - you could do so with [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) like this:

```
DECLARE 
@string1 varchar(1000) = 
'{cm_documentation_.chk_phone_call_physician}=1 & 
{cm_documentation_.txt_phone_call_code}="99441"  &   
({cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}!="" & ({local.units_mins}<5 |
{local.units_mins}>10) | {cm_documentation_.txt_units_mins}="")',

@string2 varchar(1000) = 
'{@This}="9301" | {@This}="78454" | {@This}="78453" | {@This}="78452" |   
{@This}="784514" | {@This}="78480" | {@This}="78478" | {@This}="78465" |  
{@This}="78499" | {@This}="78492" | {@This}="78491" | {@This}="78459"';

SELECT token = SUBSTRING(token, 3, stringlen)
FROM (VALUES (4),(5),(6)) s(stringlen)
CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8K(@string1+@string2, stringlen+3)
WHERE token LIKE '="'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',stringlen)+'"';
```